How can I efficiently generate every possible cluster of items such that everything within the cluster is correlated with each other?
The following is an example dataframe called matrix that I have in my program:

I have a variable called "plimit" which is currently 0.7.
I want an algorithm such that clusters are made from the dataframe. Everything in a cluster must have a correlation greater than the plimit (0.7+) with each other. The following is a list of every such cluster.
(A, A)
(A, C)
(A, E)
(A, F)
(B, B)
(B, C)
(B, E)
(C, A)
(C, B)
(C, C)
(C, E)
(D, D)
(E, A)
(E, B)
(E, C)
(E, E)
(F, A)
(G, G)
(A, C, E)
(B, C, E)
(A, B, C, E)

I want all repeats to be removed (ie remove (C, A) since (A, C) is already here). I want all all self pairs to be removed (ie remove (A, A)). Ideally, these repeats and self-pairs aren't even generated in the first place to save on computing power, though I understand if they must be made.
That should leave us with:
(A, C)
(A, E)
(A, F)
(B, C)
(B, E)
(C, E)
(A, C, E)
(B, C, E)
(A, B, C, E)

These should all be the final result with nothing more or less than these 9 clusters for this example dataframe.

So what is preventing you from applying the filters you describe on your already generated long list? This is easily done with loops and if statements... [ask]

From what I see, you only need to generate the biggest cluster (A, B, C, E), then generate (if needed) its subsets of size > 1. Oh and now that I looked more closely, how can A and B be in the same cluster?

It seems the find_cliques method of the networkx library could help you: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766241/finding-maximal-cliques-and-removing-nodes

As @Swifty suggested, the use of find_cliques from networkx works :
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

data = {
    'A': [1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1],
    'B': [0.5, 1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
    'C': [0.8, 0.9, 1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1],
    'D': [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1],
    'E': [0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 1, 0.3, 0.1],
    'F': [0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.1],
    'G': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1],
}

corr_matrix = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])

plimit = 0.7

unique_pairs = [[row, col] 
                for row in corr_matrix.index 
                for col in corr_matrix.columns 
                if corr_matrix.loc[row, col] >= plimit and col > row ]

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from(unique_pairs)
all_clusters = unique_pairs + sorted([sorted(cluster) 
                                      for cluster in nx.find_cliques(graph) 
                                      if len(cluster)>2])

However it gives only 8 clusters for your example data since A and B are not correlated with plmit = 0.7 :
>>> for i, cluster in enumerate(all_clusters, 1):
       print(f"Cluster {i}: {cluster}")

    Cluster 1: ['A', 'C']
    Cluster 2: ['A', 'E']
    Cluster 3: ['A', 'F']
    Cluster 4: ['B', 'C']
    Cluster 5: ['B', 'E']
    Cluster 6: ['C', 'E']
    Cluster 7: ['A', 'C', 'E']
    Cluster 8: ['B', 'C', 'E']

